# Problem with ggplot2 geom_line and specifying line colour

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a variable which represents performance at different time points for different individuals (time measured in months). When I use the following code:

```
ggplot(data=  AllNPa, 
       mapping = aes(x = TimeMonths, y = EMcomposite, group = subject_label)) +  
  geom_point(shape = 2, size = 1) +
  geom_line()
```

I get the plot that I need with the dots of each participant connected but I want to take it a step further and get the connecting lines in a different colour depending on another variable:

```
ggplot(data = AllNPa, 
       mapping = aes(x = TimeMonths, y = Performance, group=subject_label)) +
  geom_point(shape = 2, size = 1) +
  geom_line(colour = AllNPa$ColourVariable)
```

When I run the above code the lines connecting the dots for each participant disappear. I believe the reason is that for some participants ColourVariable changes over time so one line for this participant needs to be one colour when connecting time point 1 and 2 and another colour when connecting time point 2 and 3. And I guess R does not know how to deal with this so it just does not plot.

Do you have any suggestions how to get around this problem?

Comment: You will need to put colour in the aes()

Comment: When I do this i receive error: "Must request at least one colour from hue palette".

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include the code that gave you that error, and also include some data so others can replicate it. You can use `dput(ALLNPa)` to add the data in an easily importable format.